# Google Drive Api. How to get Free Space

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

In my project I use Google Drive API Android, now I need to know the free space.
How to get free space in Google Drive with using Google Drive API?
What should I do to get free space???

I think use it: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about
but I do not understand how.

Comment: you're correct that it's the About resource. Just subtract `usage` from `limit`

Comment: @pinoyyid is correct, you're on the right track. usage = `quotaBytesUsed` and limit = `quotaBytesTotal` which is also present in [v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/about). In [v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about), `storageQuota.limit` and `storageQuota.usage` where storageQuota.limit is equal to the total/maximum storage size. Just as mentioned, subtract limit and usage to get the free space.

Comment: This option gave me:
`About about = drive
                        .about()
                        .get()
                        .setFields("storageQuota")
                        .execute();
about.getStorageQuota().getLimit()`

Answer (score 3):

For C# admin-sdk, here is how to get it

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, 
    "service_account_creds.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
     var scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
     credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes);
}
var _service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
      HttpClientInitializer = credential,
      ApplicationName = "My Application Name",
});
var aboutRequest = _service.About.Get();
aboutRequest.Fields = "storageQuota";
var about = aboutRequest.Execute();

long usedBytes = about.StorageQuota.Usage.Value;
long totalBytes = about.StorageQuota.Limit.Value;
```